# react-native run-android command fails

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

On ubuntu 14.04 I try to launch hello world project.
I get the following output when print `react-native run-android`

> /home/jonstark/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:73
>     const setupEnvScript = /^win/.test(process.platform)
>     ^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
>       at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>       at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/jonstark/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (/home/jonstark/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:15:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

What do I do to get it working?

I tried to update nodejs with `sudo npm install -g n`

Then `node -v` shows

> v0.10.25

Answer (score 2):

Your node version is horribly outdated.  See here for steps on how to update it on Ubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version